# Applying group by on single value multiplies the value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get SUM() from 4 tables using joins and at last group by to summaries the result of each customer. The problem is that the query works good if each table has more then more record but fails and shows the double result if any table has only one record. For instance, if the table **A** has 2 records with prices 200 and 300 it will show 500 that is correct but if the table `B` Or `C` or `D` has single single record with price B = 200, C = 200, D = 200, the query will show result of table B as 400 table C as 400 and table D as 400. Kindly help me out whats wrong.

```
$query = $this -> db -> select('SUM(orders.amount_aed) AS Cash_Incoming, SUM(loan_order.amount_aed) AS Laon_Incoming, SUM(order_banks.amount) AS Bank_Incoming, SUM(order_deposit.amount_aed) AS Deposit_Incoming, orders.*, loan_order.*, order_banks.*, order_deposit.*, customers.*')
            -> from('customers')
            -> join('orders', "orders.dated BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND customers.id=orders.customer_id", 'INNER')
            -> join('loan_order', "loan_order.dated BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND customers.id=loan_order.customer_id", 'INNER')
            -> join('order_banks', "order_banks.dated BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND '$to' AND customers.id=order_banks.customer_id", 'INNER')
            -> join('order_deposit', "order_deposit.dated BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND customers.id=order_deposit.customer_id", 'INNER')
            -> group_by('customers.id')
            -> get();
        return $query -> result();
```

Comment: you can remove `orders.*, loan_order.*, order_banks.*, order_deposit.*, customers.*` and add only `customers.id`

Comment: did but same result multiplies the value

Comment: you can post your table structure with field name and your output.